# Detecting if a "net" connection is made in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a small utility to allow only specific urls to be called by untrusted code. I'm looking to have a pre-defined list of whitelisted urls, and allow them after a check.

So, I'd need to know whenever the untrusted code tries to make a connection.

Is there any way to hook something up to the `net` library, that would be triggered on every external connection? Or is there a better way altogether?

Comment: Did you try Connect? http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/logger.html

Comment: I'm looking for a way to restrict connections based from connect or another library.